# May one broker the sale non kosher restaurants?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, business

one may not do business with foods that are forbidden to eat (shulchan aruch yore dea 117)

However, if a person's business is not selling the treif item and will never comes to own any of the product of the business may one broker a deal between two other individuals? Does it matter if the buyer is Jewish or not since after the sale of the business the buyer always has the opportunity to make the business kosher?

Comment: Can you narrow down "broker a deal "? For example, if someone is a real-estate agent, and the owner of a non-kosher store wants to sell his property, I don't think his getting commission on the sale of the property is a problem. He's not having a direct transaction with the products sold in the store.